# How to compare ArrayList elements fluently?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'd like to ask you how can I compare two lists and get output with information where in the second list are an elements of first list.

**Example:**

firstList : a c b

secondList : c b a

Output : 3 1 2

I tried :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < firstList.size() ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(secondList.indexOf(firstList.get(i)));
}
```

But it's tooo slow for a lot of data. I tried two for loops, but it's slower than this. Do you have any other ideas? I'd like to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "a lot of data", it will be slow whether you have one `for` loop calling `indexOf` or two `for` loops.  Each of these `for` loops contributes O(n), even `indexOf` which is a loop in disguise.  These are O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithms.

Assuming that all elements are unique in the lists, you can run through one of the lists once, placing the desired number in a `HashMap`, which has O(1) lookup time.

Then you just need to use one `for` loop, consulting the `HashMap` instead.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < secondList.size(); i++)
{
    map.put(secondList.get(i), i + 1);
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < firstList.size() ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(map.get(firstList.get(i)));
}
```

This is O(n) and will perform better for "a lot of data".